# Font Awesome 5 works with Chrome but not Safari

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, openlayers, webpacker, font-awesome-5

Font Awesome Free works fine on Chrome but shows boxes in Safari 14.

Installed via `yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Using OpenLayers 6 and Webpacker with Rails 6 for JavaScript and CSS.`application.scss` has

`@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free';`

OpenLayers javascript (partial):

```
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style, Text, Icon} from 'ol/style';

var homeHouseholderIcon = new Style({
  text: new Text({
    text: '\uf015',                         // fa-home, unicode f015
    font: '900 18px "Font Awesome 5 Free"', // font weight must be 900
    fill: new Fill({ color: 'darkgreen'}),
    offsetX: 2,
    offsetY: 2,
  })
});

new VectorLayer({
  title: 'Locations as points',
  imageRatio: 2,
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: urlLocJSON,
    format: new GeoJSON() 
  }),
  style: homeHouseholderIcon, 
}),
```

Read through other SO posts on problems with Font Awesome. Mostly dealing with using in HTML. One using Unicode suggested trying: `Font Awesome 5 FreeR` instead of `Font Awesome 5 Free` which failed in both Chrome and Safari. None of the other comments related to my situation.

OpenLayers' [documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Text-Text.html) has little to no information on font options.